# While True Error in Tweepy while Tweeting in Python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, python-3.9

Everyone. Today, I was creating a Twitter Bot in Python using the **tweepy** module, which works perfectly. I've observed that when I use a While True command to tweet anything, it will Tweet it at first, so show me an error here it is below.

```
    Response(data={'id': '1522239311277486080', 'text': 'Alas, after a certain age every man is responsible for his face.-Albert Camus'}, includes={}, errors=[], meta={})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\varni\PycharmProjects\Twitter_Bot Version 1\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    response = client.create_tweet(text=Quotes.Quotes_Random)
  File "C:\Users\varni\PycharmProjects\Twitter_Bot Version 1\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py", line 824, in create_tweet
    return self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\varni\PycharmProjects\Twitter_Bot Version 1\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py", line 126, in _make_request
    response = self.request(method, route, params=request_params,
  File "C:\Users\varni\PycharmProjects\Twitter_Bot Version 1\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\client.py", line 99, in request
    raise Forbidden(response)
tweepy.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
```

And here is the code-

```
import config
import tweepy
import Quotes
import time

client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key=config.API_KEY,
                       consumer_secret=config.API_SECRET,
                       access_token=config.ACCESS_TOKEN,
                       access_token_secret=config.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

while True:
    # time.sleep(600)
    response = client.create_tweet(text=Quotes.Quotes_Random)
    print(response)
```

is there way to fix this error?

Comment: Your credentials are probably not valid. Double check them

Comment: the credentials are vaild then how is able to tweet without the while command then @Phantoms

Answer (score 1):

You're likely encountering this because you can't Tweet the exact same text you've already recently Tweeted.

Comment: I have  a tuple with lines of quotes and I use the random module so it is not possbile to have because everytime it would tweet something else.

Comment: Seeing as how you have a finite number of quotes and no delay between each Tweet, it's not only possible, but probable that you'll be Tweeting the exact same text you've already recently Tweeted. If your quote is randomly selected, how quickly that occurs will depend on the volume of quotes for the most part.

Comment: I just figured out the problem it is not time or while command it 403 forbidden of tweepy I noticed if I tell it to tweet normally there is like a 10% chance it would work I tried everything but it doesn't work always get same error but if run for few tries out of them out is going to work I am not just understanding why it works sometimes it doesn't also btw I have checked everything it doesn't seem to be error from myside I assume